¿Que impresora me recomiendan para un punto de venta en laravel? solo quiere que despues de realizar una venta salgan esos datos
Que impresora me recomiendan para un punto de venta en laravel, que sea facil de instalar y en automatico al realizar una venta se envie el ticket de los productos de esa venta
